# How to supply choices to a formset, if choices come from queryset or other view logic?

Tags: python, django, formset

How to supply `choices` to a formset, if choices come from queryset or other view logic?

I have formset setup in `forms.py` as following:

```
class MCQuestionAnswerForm(forms.Form):
    question = forms.CharField()
    mcq_answer_choice = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect)


MCQuestionAnswerFormSet = formset_factory(MCQuestionAnswerForm, extra=0)
```

I need to supply in `views.py` different set of `choices` to the formset instance, where `choices` will be a result of a queryset or other view logic. Can I use for that matter form_kwargs? If so, how can I do that?

**Edit:**

Sorry, I was not clear about `choices` I want to alter. The `choices` is the initial parameter in the `mcq_answer_choice` field

```
    class MCQuestionAnswerForm(forms.Form):
    question = forms.CharField()
    mcq_answer_choice = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=SOME_CHOICES_LIST)
```

`SOME_CHOICES_LIST` will be supplied in `views.py`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation

```
class MCQuestionAnswerForm(forms.Form):
     question = forms.CharField()
     mcq_answer_choice = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect)

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.extra = kwargs.pop('extra')
         super(MyArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

         # You have now use the value of self.extra to construct or alter your form body
         # For example:
         self.fields['mcq_answer_choice'].initial = self.extra

MCQuestionAnswerFormSet = formset_factory(MCQuestionAnswerForm, extra=0)
```

Comment: Thank you OptimusCrime. Will your solution still work with my new "Edit"?